# hacking gitlab - adding a field to the issue model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, gitlab

So I find myself needing to add a "custom" field (an external ticket ref) to the gitlab issue model.

Not being a ruby guy, I've been kinda fighting this and have gotten so far but have hit a brick wall.

I have added a migration file

```
class AddExternalRefToIssues < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :issues, :external_ref, :string
    add_index :issues, :external_ref
  end
end
```

and managed to get that loaded into the database by running these commands

```
rm /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/upgrade-status/*
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

I checked the postgres table

```
 id | [snip] | external_ref 
----+-------+--------------
  1 |        | 
(1 row)
```

so the column is there. Indeed, as I can read & write the `external_ref` attribute in the rails console

```
irb(main):018:0> i = Issue.find(1)
=> #<Issue id: 1, title: "demo", ...[snip]..., external_ref: "123">
```

but now I am at a loss of what to do next, as the api call `api/v4/projects/1/issues/1` returns

```
{"id":1,"iid":1,"project_id":1,"title":"demo",[snip] , "subscribed":true}
```

i.e. my `external_ref` field is not shown

I have tried hacking around, modifying a couple of files like `app/serializers/issue_entity.rb` and adding `expose :external_ref` and restarting gitlab to no effect

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to get & put a value for this new attribute ?

I would also appreciate someone telling me how to add an api that would allow me to search on this field.

thanks

Comment: Backreference to [relevant GitLab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/1906#note_28952232).

Answer (score 3):

So, I eventually worked it out.

create a new file called */opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/migrate/20170505102713_add_external_ref_to_issues.rb*

with the following contents:

```
class AddExternalRefToIssues < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :issues, :external_ref, :string
    add_index :issues, :external_ref
  end
end
```

make the following changes to

*/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/api/entities.rb*

```
class IssueBasic < ProjectEntity
  expose :external_ref
```

*/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/api/entities.rb*

```
  params :issues_params do
    optional :external_ref, type: String, desc: 'external reference'

  params :issue_params do
    optional :external_ref, type: String, desc: 'external reference'
```

execute

```
rm /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/upgrade-status/*
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
gitlab-ctl restart
```

and now you can write and read the `external_ref` column